# Move the selected checkbox to the top of the list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to click on each item and the selected item goes first in the list and gets rendered at the top.
Now the problem is when I click on each item, it goes to the top but the item which replaces it also gets checked.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
  let newData = [
    {
      Id: '1',
      Name: 'a',
      Group: 'GroupA'
    },
    {
      Id: '2',
      Name: 'b',
      Group: 'GroupB',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      Id: '3',
      Name: 'c',
      Group: 'GroupC'
    },
    {
      Id: '4',
      Name: 'd',
      Group: 'GroupD'
    },
    {
      Id: '5',
      Name: 'e',
      Group: 'GroupA'
    },
    {
      Id: '6',
      Name: 'f',
      Group: 'GroupA'
    },
    {
      Id: '7',
      Name: 'g',
      Group: 'GroupB'
    },
    {
      Id: '8',
      Name: 'h',
      Group: 'GroupC'
    }
  ];

  // Separate the data by Group
  let groupData = {};
  newData.forEach((item) => {
    const { Group } = item;
    if (!groupData[Group]) {
      groupData[Group] = [];
    }
    groupData[Group].push(item);
  });

  // Function to handle checkbox click
  function handleCheckboxClick(item) {
    item.selected = !item.selected;

    // Move selected item to the top of its Group list
    const Group = item.Group;
    const index = groupData[Group].findIndex((data) => data.Id === item.Id);
    groupData[Group].splice(index, 1);
    groupData[Group].unshift(item);
  }
</script>

{#each Object.keys(groupData) as Group}
  <h3>{Group}</h3>
  <div>
    {#each groupData[Group] as item}
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          bind:checked={item.selected}
          on:click={() => handleCheckboxClick(item)}
        />
        {item.Name}
      </label>
    {/each}
  </div>
{/each}

<style>
  h3 {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
</style>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-cjqvpz?file=src%2Froutes%2F%2Bpage.svelte

Comment: on stackblitz, i just see some npm errors and a lightbulb with a crack. can you get this working as a stack snippet that is viewable on SO, and also make it a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: ok, stackblitz is working now. what i see, is that whenever you check a checkbox, it moves up, but the checkmark that is now on it's place, also gets checked with that same mouse click. did you try some "on mouse up"? if the issue is still there, try to place some very small delay on the "on mouse up" event.

Comment: i think you can also do this in pure htmlcss, by doing something like `display:flex` and `:checked{order:-9999};`.

Comment: for me, it took more than 20 minutes before I could test and see this problem that you could have simplified in a few lines here in a snippet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without using the Svelte framework or Javascript. Just pure HTML, and pure CSS:

```css
div { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
label:has(input:checked) { order: -9999; }
```

```html
<h3>Topic</h3>
<div>
  <label> <input type=checkbox> q </label>
  <label> <input type=checkbox> w </label>
  <label> <input type=checkbox> e </label>
</div>
<h3>Topic</h3>
<div>
  <label> <input type=checkbox> r </label>
  <label> <input type=checkbox> t </label>
  <label> <input type=checkbox> y </label>
</div>
<h3>Topic</h3>
<div>
  <label> <input type=checkbox> u </label>
  <label> <input type=checkbox> i </label>
  <label> <input type=checkbox> o </label>
</div>
```

You can `display:flex` the parent containers of the checkboxes, and use `order:-99999` to re-order the elements inside the flex.

Notice the clever use of `:has`, to reference the label, which has the checkbox, not the checkbox itself (e.g. if you use `label > input`, the styles will apply to the input).